# Why does every adb command take several minutes?

Tags: adb, command-line, lineageos

I've run `adb devices` and `adb push some-stuff /sdcard`, and both commands take several minutes. Once `adb push` gets started though, it races through the file, so the throughput is fine. It just takes an extremely long time to get started on processing the command.

```
$ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Revision 8.0.0_r17
$ uname --kernel-name --kernel-release --kernel-version --machine --processor --hardware-platform --operating-system 
Linux 4.13.12-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Nov 8 11:54:06 CET 2017 x86_64 unknown unknown GNU/Linux
```

The phone is a Samsung SM-A300FU (aka. A3) running a recent LineageOS.

Comment: Have you found the cause? I'm experiencing this right now.

Comment: @marczellm No, sorry. I haven't seen this for a while though, and I no longer have the same hardware or software.